# Can you rely on the permutation of a ciphertext for secrecy?

Tags: random-number-generator, permutation, aont

Say you have a message and you run it through an all-or-nothing transform. A transform that requires every single block in the correct order in order to recover *any* data. Each block is indistinguishable from random noise. Now shuffle them using a seeded crypto RNG.

Say the transform gives you at least 34 blocks (which can be arranged in ~2^128 permutations). Can this structure be considered safe? There's no actual key involved, unless you count the RNG seed.

Comment: The RNG seed _is a key_, as it needs to be kept secret for security, and you need it to decrypt the ciphertext. You’ve invented a very slow “wide” block cipher based on a keyed permutation (deterministic shuffling)

Comment: I'm wondering... aren't AONT's commonly block mode specific? Sorry, just thinking out loud here.